# Reproduce bash behavior with pipes & never ending commands

Tags: c, bash, pipe

I'm on a project of creating a terminal shell from C (with Bash as a reference) and I enventually had to deal with pipes.
The way I made them worked with basic commands like `ls | rev | wc -l`
However my program enter a never-ending loop when I try to pipe commands that never ends like this one: `base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 1000`; Bash does not.
The way I created my pipeline make my program wait for `base64` to end before calling `head`.
I don't understand when and how I am supposed to wait & execute commands anymore.
How can I reproduce Bash's behavior with such piped commands in C ? Did I make a simple mistake or should I totally rethink my system ?

Here is in pseudo-code how I do my command execution. It lacks details & security like closing the pipes but the whole idea is present.

```
while (command)
{
    pipe(fd);
    if (!fork())
    {
       dup2();
       execve(command);
    }
    wait();
    command = command->next;
}
```

Comment: There are multiple processes in a pipeline that all have to run in parallel, otherwise it'll deadlock if any of them exceed the pipe buffer (65k on Linux)

Comment: @thatotherguy Should i just wait for the last command in the pipeline to finish before displaying my prompt instead of waiting them all ?

Comment: You can do either, as long as all processes run in parallel (i.e. don't wait() until all processes have started)

Comment: The whole point of a pipe is that it has a limited-size buffer, and writers will block *automatically* when the buffer gets full. Likewise, a reader will block if the buffer is empty. Finally, the writer will get a signal if the reader closes their end (as will happen when `head` exits). You don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

Get rid of the wait() for starters.

But there's more.  Not that I'm an expert, but from observing bash behavior, I have learned that all components in a pipe are executed simultaneously in parallel

AFAIK, bash ( or perhaps the kernel implementation of the fifo ) will generate signals to a process when another process on the other side of the pipe has closed the pipe.   'base64 /dev/urandom' terminates because it received a signal when the head closed it's stdin.

As you have seen, base64 /dev/urandom never ends by itself.

Going forward, kick off all of the processes, creating fifos that have their stdout and stdin connected.  I hope this gets you going in the right direction.  There's a lot of discussion of how to use fifos out there so hopefully this is a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I remember that head send a SIGPIPE signal when it closes its stdin (when in a pipe). I'll try to modify my wait() like @thatotherguy said. thanks for your answer

Comment: SIGPIPE when writing to a closed fifo is indeed a kernel feature, so you don't have to worry about it when writing a shell

Comment: `head` doesn't send the signal; the kernel does when `base64` tries to write to a pipe whose other end is closed.